# Terraform apply failing for azure storage account premium type

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-storage-account

We are facing unexpected behavior with the terraform applying stage while creating premium type of Storage account.

Terraform version "~> 1.2"

Terraform v1.2.0
on linux_amd64

Tf- code

```
resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "staccount-endpoint" {
  count = var.create_private_endpoint ? 1 : 0

  name                = var.privatelink_name
  location            = var.rg_location
  resource_group_name = var.sa_rg
  subnet_id           = data.azurerm_subnet.sa_subnet.id

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = format("%s-connection", var.privatelink_name)
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_storage_account.storage_account.id
    subresource_names              = ["file"]
    is_manual_connection           = false
  }

  tags = var.tags

}
```

tfvarfile value for PE

```
privatelink_name = "my-pe"

allowed_subnets      = ["xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"]

sa_account_tier      = "Premium"
sa_replication_type  = "LRS"
sa_account_kind      = "StorageV2"
sa_access_tier       = "Hot"
sa_tls_version        = "TLS1_2"
```

Initialization phase as below

```
Initializing the backend...

Successfully configured the backend "azurerm"! Terraform will automatically
use this backend unless the backend configuration changes.

Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/azurerm...
- Installing hashicorp/azurerm v3.60.0...
- Installed hashicorp/azurerm v3.60.0 (signed by HashiCorp)
```

Apply failing with below error

```
Error: creating Private Endpoint "my-pe" (Resource Group "my-rg"): network.PrivateEndpointsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="InvalidValuesForRequestParameters" Message="Call to Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts failed. Error message: Values for request parameters are invalid: GroupId: file." Details=[]
│ 
│   with azurerm_private_endpoint.staccount-endpoint[0],
│   on main.tf line 23, in resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "staccount-endpoint":
│   23: resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "staccount-endpoint" {
```

Comment: doesnt the subresource_names need to be `File` instead of `file`

Answer (score 1):

> Error: creating Private Endpoint "my-pe" (Resource G roupmyrg")network.PrivateEndpointsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure

When attempting to create a private endpoint in a storage account with the `Premium tier`, I encounter the same error.

[image]

Here are the `sub-resource types` that support private endpoints in `Azure Storage Premium tier`.

1. blob: Private endpoints can be used to access and manage blobs in a `premium tier storage` account over a private connection.
2. web : Private endpoints allow you to access static websites hosted in a `premium tier storage` account over a private network connection.

To create a private endpoint for a storage account with `file sub resources`, you should use the Standard tier instead of the Premium tier.

Here is a sample code to create a private endpoint for a storage account

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "storage-rg" {
  name     = "storag-rg"
  location = "West Europe"
}
data "azurerm_subnet" "storagesubnet" {
  name                 = "default"
  virtual_network_name = "storagevnet"
  resource_group_name  = "storag-rg"
}
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "demostorage" {
  name                     = "prodstoracc"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.storage-rg.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.storage-rg.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}
resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "privateendpoint" {
  count               = 1
  name                = "my-pe"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.storage-rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.storage-rg.name
  subnet_id           = data.azurerm_subnet.storagesubnet.id

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "my-pe-connection"
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_storage_account.samplestorage.id
    subresource_names              = ["file"]
    is_manual_connection           = false
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = "Production"
  }
}
```

**Terraform Apply:**

[image]

Reference:  [Blob Storage feature support in Azure Storage accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-feature-support-in-storage-accounts) & [Creating a private endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-private-endpoints#creating-a-private-endpoint)

Comment: But my requirement is to have fileshare pvt endpoint and the storage account should be premium kind by considering the high reead write performance for AKS fileshare pvc

Comment: File sub resources are not supported in the Premium tier of storage account.

Answer (score 0):

Try `account_kind = "FileStorage"`, this worked for me.